# creating SQL query using aliases and COUNT

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please help me to create a query using aliases and COUNT. I have **only one table**, which contains all the necessary information but since I have to use COUNT to get the number of persons included in the final result, unfortunately I`m forced to use aliases as I understand.

I have companies, cities and persons working in these companies.
As a result I have to have the number of people working in every company in every city.
Initially I tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT (employee_name) FROM (SELECT company_city_name, company_name FROM mytable)
```

Here I get the error saying I have to use aliases.

I also tried to combine "SELECT COUNT (employee_name) FROM mytable" and "SELECT company_city_name, company_name FROM mytable" (since these two queries are working separately):

```
SELECT COUNT (employee_name)
FROM mytable AND SELECT company_city_name, company_name FROM mytable
```

Not working, get an error. I still don`t understand why I can`t use AND to make it work. Anyway, with aliases I`m totally confused. I have something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT (employee_name)
FROM (SELECT company_city_name AS city_name, company_name AS company FROM mytable AS t1)
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(employee_name)
FROM (SELECT company_city_name, company_name FROM mytable)
```

You are referring to `employee_name`, but there is no name in the subquery.  This version should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(employee_name)
FROM (SELECT company_city_name, company_name, employee_name FROM mytable) t
--------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

But I have no idea why you would want a subquery for this.

Why do I think that you want an aggregation?

```
select company_name, company_city_name, count(*) as num_employees
from mytable
group by company_name, company_city_name;
```

Comment: Thank you, the last example (aggregation) is working for me. So no aliases needed after all..                                            I would have never guessed it is possible to make a query like this because you are actually not using "employees" separately.